# Character for encoding cp1252 - android studio?

Tags: android-studio, character-encoding, android-studio-2.2

I imported this project to my android studio ([THIS](https://github.com/osmandapp/Osmand)).

But get me bellow errors :

[image]

I changed it but don't work :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looking randomly at the `GeocodingUtilities.java` file, it contains a line with Cyrillic characters:

```
public static final String[] SUFFIXES = new String[]{
"av.", "avenue", "просп.", "пер.", "пр.", "заул.", "проспект", "переул.",     "бул.", "бульвар", "тракт"};
```

Those cannot be mapped in code page `Windows-1252`. Now, I don't know android-studio at all, but you should check if you can find a setting to set the encoding for files. Change it to `UTF-8`.

Comment: @JoJoRoid how did you download this project exactly? Could it be that somehow `git` is using wrong encoding or something?

Comment: I Downloaded zip then import it in my android studio .

Comment: @JoJoRoid when importing, were your encoding settings already set at `utf-8`? If not, you should try again. What unzipping tool did you use?

Comment: 1-No . 2-Winrar

Comment: @JoJoRoid So, if you try importing again, does it work?